# Firebase Database - How to structure ancestral tree

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say we have three different types, `GreatGrandma`, `Grandma`, and `Mom`. So as you probably imagined their ancestral relationship looks like this.

```
 - GreatGrandma
    - Grandma
        - Mom
```

Since we don't want to nest our entire data in a single JSON tree, as it would simply be too large, we might expect the structured too look something like this.

```
"greatGrandmas": {
    "$great_grandma_key": {
        "name": "Jane Smith",
        "birthDate": "1970-01-01"
    }       
} 

"grandmas": {
    "$great_grandma_key": {
        "$grandma_key": {
            "name": "Jane Smith",
            "birthDate": "1970-01-01"
        }
    }       
} 

"moms": {
    "$great_grandma_key": {
        "$grandma_key": {
            "$mom_key": {
                "name": "Jane Smith",
                "birthDate": "1970-01-01"
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Now let's say we want to query for moms. If we know the GreatGrandma and Grandma that's easy.

```
firebase.database()
        .ref('moms')
        .child(greatGrandmaKey)
        .child(grandmaKey);
        .on('child_added', function (snapshot) { ... });
```

We could then add a size limit or equalTo filter.

But lets say we want to get all Mom types for a certain GreatGrandma. We could do the following.

```
firebase.database()
        .ref('moms')
        .child(greatGrandmaKey)
        .on('value', function (snapshot) { ... });
```

However we would not be able to apply any filters here. We would be forced to get the whole data. This is not scaleable.

How can I build a firebase database such that I can query for children with the full or partial ancestral path?

In addition I want to be able to restrict access to the entire tree, and only grant access to certain Mom nodes.

Comment: This is a good use case for a graph database I believe.

Comment: @AliGajani could you be more specific? Particularly, describe how this might look in Firebase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example in   the moms part you are still creating a deep node relation that is why you cannot do efficient queries in the mom node and you would get  big son responses even if you only want a small portion of the data, there are many ways to achieve what you want, a couple of options are:

You could set the references like this for each type in order to be able to call only the info you needed in this case the data or the children of a type, this would be helpful if you want of find relations upstream and downstream:

```
"greatGrandmas": {
 "$great_grandma_key": {
    "data":{
      "name": "Jane Smith",
      "birthDate": "1970-01-01",
    },
    "grandmas":{
      "$grandma_key":true
    },
    "moms":{
      "$mom_key":true
    }
 }       
}

"grandmas": {
 "$grandma_key": {
    "data":{
      "name": "Jane Smith",
      "birthDate": "1970-01-01",
    },
    "great_grandmas":{
      "$great_grandma_key":true
    },
    "moms":{
      "$mom_key":true
    }
 }       
}

"moms": {
 "$mom_key": {
    "data":{
      "name": "Jane Smith",
      "birthDate": "1970-01-01",
    },
    "great_grandmas":{
      "$great_grandma_key":true
    },
    "grandmas":{
      "$grandma_key":true
    }
 }       
}
```

If you only want to find relations from the lowest node up in this case moms and grandmas you could do something like this:

```
moms:{
 "$mom_key": {
   "name": "Jane Smith", 
   "birthDate": "1970-01-01"
   "great_grandma":$great_grandma_key
   "grandma":$grandma_key
 }
}

grandmas:{
 "$grandma_key": {
   "name": "Jane Smith", 
   "birthDate": "1970-01-01"
   "great_grandma":$great_grandma_key
 }
}

great_grandmas:{
 "$great_grandma_key": {
   "name": "Jane Smith", 
   "birthDate": "1970-01-01"
 }
}
```

In this case you could only query by specific child node value to get the relations but it would only be upstream.

It depends how are you going to query and read the data, who's gonna have access and the balance between easy to access -vs- the complexity of keeping the database consistent

The queries would be like:

REF_TO_MOM.orderByChild('grandma').equalTo($grandma_key).on('child_added',callback)

This one would get al the moms with the same grandma

here is the ref to the query types and how you can use them

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#filtering_data

To get the same result with the first structure you could do this:

```
MOMS_REF.child($mom_key).child('grandmas').on('child_added',function(snapshot){
     //Here you only have the key of the mom's grandma so you can call a single event listener to get the rest of the data , this is a fairly common practice in firebase with very low network and data cost, to keep the data flow efficient i grouped the properties under a "data" node to avoid bringing unnecessary children in this call

    GRANDMA_REF.child(snapshot.key).child('data').once('value',function(snap){

       if(snap.val()){
         //Here you can append to a dictionary or array the name, birthDate and the key of the grandmas of one mom. 
       }
     })
   }
})
```

Comment: Could you show some examples of how the queries would look like?

Comment: Updated, with a query that works for the  second example of structure, the first structure doesn't require queries you only need to make references to the paths like  MOMS_REF.child('grandma').on('child_added',callback)

Comment: That query I understood. How would you get the same results if the database was structured in the first way?

Comment: The issue I had with the second way is that you can't combine orderBy filters, so you use up your only one.

Comment: another hack that some people use to break the only one orderBy filter  is to create childs specific for queries by mixing the properties  they want  for example query:filter1_filter2 and use the startAt,endAt and equalTo methods to  get a specific range of values or a specific value. For example search latitude and longitude combination when you don't want to use a GeoHash they create coords:lat_192021_lon_900101, but this depends on the final use you want to have

Comment: Other way that is sometimes valid but mostly inefficient, so is only recommended when the possible results will always be few(for example you are always sure you won't receive more than 3 matchers) is filter by only one category and in the callback dismiss the children that doesn't match the  multiple filters criteria... the problem with this approach is  even if you only want one value and only use one value, still there values will be sent to you by firebase

Comment: Yea, definitely don't want to use the method mentioned directly above. I need it to scale.

Comment: Also, I noticed with the first structure your query `MOMS_REF.child($mom_key).child('grandmas')` requires the $mom_key. For my use case I wouldn't know the $mom_Key, the point would be to query for Mom types. Looks like the second structure method is the only way. That was what I was originally thinking. I was just hoping there was a better way. Thanks for the help!